# Отправка почты через php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть форма отправки почты. Отправляю в виде HTML, пишу ссылку, `<a href=site.ru/product.php?id=1>Мой сайт</a>` и вот ссылка приходит мне на почту, но в таком виде `<a href=site.ru>Мой сайт</a>`, то есть `product.php?id=1` куда-то вырезается... кто сталкивался с этим?

Вот код:

```
$subject = "Тема";
$to = "test@yandex.ru";
$from = "test@yandex.ru";
$message = ' 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Письмо< /title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <p>Это письмо пришло вам с <a href=site.ru/product.php?id=1>Мой сайт</a></p> 
    </body> 
</html>'; 
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: тест <$from>\r\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Экранируйте "/" после site.ru. Т.е. должно быть site.ru/product.php

Comment: сделайте из href=site.ru/product.php?id=1 вот такое
href='http://site.ru/product.php?id=1' (добавить hhtp:// и кавычки)

Comment: одинарная кавычка в данном случае не уместна

Comment: а кто мешает сделать не $message = ' а $message = " ?? помоему было бы сразу и наглядно и легко использовать внутри тогда одинарные

Comment: все заработало, после того как я поставил скобки href='http://site.ru/product.php?id=1'

Answer (score -1):

А что за хостинг у Вас? У меня Ваш код отлично сработал и письмо пришло с полной ссылкой. Правда пришлось оставить только это:

```
$message = ' 
        <p>Это письмо пришло вам с <a href=site.ru/product.php?id=1>Мой сайт</a></p> 
';
```

а все остальное удалить.